# Python: Updating Value for Nested Dictionary Inside a Class Function

Tags: python, class, dictionary, nested

I'm trying to create a class to create a student grade information system.

I'm having problems when trying to create the "update" function inside my class.

Here is what my class looks like:

```
class StudentManagement(object):

    def __init__(self): 
        """ Initializes a dictionary to keep track of students' grades """
        self.student_dict = {}


    def add_student(self,num_students): 
        """ Add students to your student dictionary. All newly added students will have 0 for assignments."""

        for i in range(num_students):
            student_id = input("Type in student ID for student " + str(i+1) + ": ")
            self.student_dict[student_id] = 0
        print(self.student_dict)


    def add_initial_assignments(self, assignment_name): # list of assignment names
        """ Add assignments to student dictionary. All assignments will be set to 0"""

        self.assignment_dict = {}
        for assignment in assignment_name:
            self.assignment_dict[assignment] = 0
        for key in self.student_dict:
            self.student_dict[key] = self.assignment_dict
        print(self.student_dict)


    def add_new_assignment(self, new_assignment): # one new assignment only
        """ Add a new assignment to existing assignments in student dictionary"""

        for key in self.student_dict:
            self.student_dict[key][new_assignment] = 0
        print(self.student_dict)


    def update(self, student_id, assignment_name, value):
        """Updates the assignment score for a given student id"""

        for key in self.student_dict:
            if key == student_id:
                self.student_dict[student_id][assignment_name] = value
        print(self.student_dict)

new = StudentManagement()
print("ADDED 3 students")
new.add_student(3)
print("\n")
print("ADDED Initial assignments")
new.add_initial_assignments(['Exam 1','Exam 2'])
print("\n")
print("ADDED new Quiz assignment")
new.add_new_assignment('Quiz 1')
print("\n")
print("UPDATED score for student Student_1")
new.update(student_id = 'Student_1',assignment_name = 'Quiz 1',value = 100)
```

When I update a student's grade on an assignment with that last line of code, all the student's Quiz 1 grade becomes 100, rather than just for Student_1. I'm not sure if I'm understanding the self.student_dict correctly. I don't want to create an entire new dictionary every time I want to update a student's information. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why one change of one student's dictionary changes all of the students' dictionaries is because they are all assigned to the same dictionary in memory. This is because in the add_initial_assignments function, you use the code:

```py
key in self.student_dict:
            self.student_dict[key] = self.assignment_dict
```

This code doesn't make a new dictionary for each student, rather they are all connected to the same one. All you have to do is add `.copy()` at the end of it like this:

```py
for key in self.student_dict:
            self.student_dict[key] = self.assignment_dict.copy()
```

This way, it creates a seperate dictionary for each one and now the code should work. If you don't understand why they are all connected to the same dictionary, it is because you are setting all the students equal to one same variable that is a dictionary, which is also mutable. Consider this code:

```py
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = list1
list1.pop()
print(list1, list2)

Output:
[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
```

You are basically doing the same thing as shown above and `.copy()` fixes the problem because it actually creates a seperate, independant dictionary for each student.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense to me :)